# extjs 3.4 markInvalid for a grid

Tags: extjs, jqgrid

Is there a way to add a markInvalid to a grid when the store is empty? I can't find it in the API documentation for editorGridPanel.
I have a markInvalid which is working for cells
[image]

But I want to have a markInvalid for all the grid if it's empty, but I don't know how to make it, and if there is an option for that.

Comment: You should write a renderer and apply it to each column. It would decide when to make column invalid.

Comment: @Riku which listeners event do I have to call?Afteredit? The array has to fire when I click on a submit button, so do I put the renderer on the grid or on the submit?

Comment: on the grid column, renderer is called when value changes in grid.

Answer (score 0):

what if you load your store with an array of empty data ?

suppose is an array store

```
store.loadData([['','',''],['','','']]); // loads two records of empty data
```

Comment: I don't have any store, there are free text and prewritten datas for each column

Answer (score 0):

Try using [emptyText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-emptyText), html tags are accepted

Oops, Available since: 4.1.0